# Scheme to Clojure

Tags: clojure, scheme

I have a Scheme function that has the following attributes:
It counts the number of leaf nodes a nested list structure, ignoring #f. It uses a recursive procedure:

- If the input is an empty list, this is the base case that returns 0.
- If the input is a pair whose car is not a list:

  - If the car is #f, we recurse on the cdr and return that.
  - Otherwise we count the car as 1, and add that to the result of recursing on the cdr.
- Finally, we recurse on both the car and cdr, and add them together.

How can I turn the following code into the programming language Clojure?

```
(define (x lis)
  (cond ((null? lis) 0) 
        ((not (list? (car lis))) 
         (cond 
          ((eq? (car lis) #f) (x (cdr lis))) 
          (else (+ 1 (x (cdr lis)))))) 
        (else (+ (x (car lis)) (x (cdr lis))))))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The transparent translation is

```
(defn x [lis]
  (cond (empty? lis) 0
        (not (coll? (first lis)))
        (if (= (first lis) false)
          (x (rest lis))
          (inc (x (rest lis))))
        :else (+ (x (first lis)) (x (rest lis)))))
```

Or did you ask about clojure specific solution?

**Edited (clojure specific solution ver.1).**

```
(defn x [lis]  
  (count (filter (partial not= false) (flatten lis))))
```

Comment: Your clojure version may give unexpected results if you `flatten` the list. If the #f (or is it `false` in your code?) is within the list, and not necessarily at the front of the list (like the OP wanted it to be), then it would return a incorrect result. If you could, for future viewers, please add a recursive solution that involves some mapping function.

Comment: AFAIK the "#f" is a "false" in scheme. Please give an example of problem nested list structure.